# How can I automate the quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create a quiz in html and JavaScript I have the following code for my HTML. I just wonder is there a different technique for creating quizzes like this. What I mean is I will need to type lots of html and then edit every id element. Is it how it is always done in production?

```html
<p>What is the capital of Poland?</p>
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" value="wasras" id="warsaw" name="question2" />
    <label for="warsaw">(<span>K</span>A) Warsaw</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="moscow" id="mosco" name="question2" />
    <label for="mosco">(<span>K</span>B) Moscow</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="london" id="londo" name="question2" />
    <label for="londo">(<span>K</span>C) London</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: usually a serverside script renders the HTML. Boiler plate code is filled in with the variables by the server side code and then the complete code is outputted to the client.

Comment: Typically you'd have some server-side software written in PHP, C#, etc, along with a database behind that to store the questions. But that's a very very broad discussion.

Comment: @SatejS I have not downvoted, however this type of question is extremely broad, and not entirely clear where OP is having the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew there was a better way to do that other than type that in plain html. At least now I have a clear picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use javascript (especially jQuery) you can do it in client side.

You can create a `json` object with all your Q&A then iterate it.

Please read the comments and let me know if something not clear.

```js
var qna = [
  {
    q: 'What is the capital of Poland?',
    a: [
      'wasras',
      'moscow',
      'london'
    ]
  },
  {
    q: 'What is the capital of Poland?',
    a: [
      'wasras',
      'moscow',
      'london'
    ]
  }
];

// iterate each question
$.each(qna, function(qIndex, q) {
  // create wrapper div for each question
  var wDiv = $('<div />'),
      // headline 3 for the question text
      qElm = $('<h3>' + q.q + '</h3>'),
      // list for the answers
      ansUl = $('<ul />');

  // iterate each answer
  $.each(q.a, function(i, a) {
    // append li with label and input for each answer and append it to the ul
    $('<li />').html('<label><input type="radio" value="' + a + '" name="group_' + qIndex + '" />' + a + '</label>').appendTo(ansUl);
  });

  // append the h3 and the ul to the wrapper div
  wDiv.append(qElm).append(ansUl);
  // append the wrapper div to to quiz container
  $('#quiz').append(wDiv);
});

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="quiz"></div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

References to the jQuery functions:

- [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: wow, this is really cool. It is going to save a lot of typing doing it with Jquery. Thanks a lot. I am going to use it in my scripts.
However, there is one downside, what if the user turns JavaScript off?

Comment: I'm glad to hear :-)  It will not work if javascript disabled but a lot of website doesn't work without javascript. You can display a message to the user that he need to enable javascript or move this logic to the server.